# How do we setup communication between 2 EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, communication

How to establish the communication between two EC2 instances.

can i directly ping to each other via their IPV4. Do I need to setup inbound rules in security group? Any tips/pointers or steps will be helpful

Answer (score -1):

InsideVPC security group attaching to both instances helps to allow to communication as inbound rule defines to accept communication.

Comment: Assigning the same Security Group to multiple resources is not necessarily an appropriate solution.. Security Groups are applied _individually_ to each resource. Merely being "in" the same Security Group does not guarantee that the resources can communicate. The Security Group would need to **permit Inbound connections from itself** to permit the resources to communicate. It is normally better to apply Security Groups to each resource based upon their _specific_ function. For example, a web server would have a different Security Group to an app server, with rules that let them communicate.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).